# Can't show the shape of a spark dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

FYI, pyspark don't have atribut `.shape` lie pandas. So, here's what I did

`print((df.count(), len(df.columns)))`

The error message

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-aefe947885ec> in <module>
----> 1 print((df.count(), len(df.columns)))

/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-7.1.3-1.cdh7.1.3.p0.4992530/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py in count(self)
    521         2
    522         """
--> 523         return int(self._jdf.count())
    524 
    525     @ignore_unicode_prefix

/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-7.1.3-1.cdh7.1.3.p0.4992530/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1255         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1256         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1257             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1258 
   1259         for temp_arg in temp_args:

/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-7.1.3-1.cdh7.1.3.p0.4992530/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     61     def deco(*a, **kw):
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
     65             s = e.java_exception.toString()

/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-7.1.3-1.cdh7.1.3.p0.4992530/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329             else:
    330                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o2492.count.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 142.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 142.0 (TID 7646, adaijktwrk04.adreach.co, executor 338): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 338 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Container from a bad node: container_e34_1626420344890_0830_01_000350 on host: adaijktwrk04.adreach.co. Exit status: 143. Diagnostics: [2021-09-03 05:48:30.176]Container killed on request. Exit code is 143
[2021-09-03 05:48:30.177]Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143. 
[2021-09-03 05:48:30.177]Killed by external signal
.
Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1891)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1879)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1878)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1878)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:927)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:927)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:927)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2112)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2061)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2050)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:738)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2067)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2088)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2107)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2132)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:990)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:385)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:989)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollect(SparkPlan.scala:309)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$count$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2836)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$count$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2835)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$52.apply(Dataset.scala:3370)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3369)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.count(Dataset.scala:2835)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

How to know the size of a pyspark dataframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They way you are checking is the correct way to get the shape of the dataframe, but according to the error you received it seems you have a problem with Spark on your machine.

When a container (Spark executor) runs out of memory, YARN automatically kills it. This causes a "Container killed on request. Exit code is 137" error. These errors can happen in different job stages, both in narrow and wide transformations.

This forum here describes how to resolve your issue:
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/container-killed-on-request-137-emr/

Comment: No it doesn’t seem like it.